# Can AOP be used for generating Notifications in java?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have to write the logic for generating notifications based on a property change, for instance our in our Application we have to maintain phases of Work Orders, so there will be an Entity as WorkOrder whose property is 'phase', that can be changed in the course of different activities. So now I have to develop logic to generate a notification when the phase is changed. And I want this logic should be loosely coupled, so I am thinking of using AOP's 'After Returning' functionality, where I can check whether old value is replaced for the property, if so generate the notification.

Comment: Sure, why couldn't it be?

Comment: or you could use spring-integration

Comment: @JEY What does spring-integration have to do with this?

Comment: emit message on software bus and component registering for them loosely coupled. And in the tag there is spring so i assume he is using spring

Comment: The question is so unspecific that you will not get useful answers. I also say "yes", but that does not help you. Show us some code, ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), and we can show you a solution.

Comment: Hi thank you all, so I am starting to implement this by using AOP, and @kriegaex actually I have not started coding it, I asked this question as I don't have enough experience to take the design based decisions.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a discussion forum but a q/a forum about actual, concrete programming problems. Please respect that.